# User Agent string for Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 ?

Tags: android, user-agent

Please let me know if Anyone knows the user agent string for Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 device. Or please share how to configure the Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 emulator on Eclipse android. I have been searching this about a day and  I couldn't find out.

Please share me if anyone knows.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look here http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator

Comment: yes. i have seen this. But my AVD manager doesn't shown options like Step:1(as you mentioned link). Then how can i add third party add-on's ? i'm getting more trouble to figured it out. Any thoughts ?

Comment: See this blog, may be its helpful for you; http://andjaswahyu.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/how-to-add-samsung-galaxy-sdk-add-on-and-samsung-galaxy-emulator-into-eclipse/

Comment: Sorry getting close but not up to. In fact i tried that too before posting this but i can not set the device property in emulator. Thanks for your response. And please share anything you know about the User Agent String. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but found this nifty little website that has links out to every User Agent string imaginable

http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings

As for the Tab 4 - http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/brand642368/samsung-galaxy-tab-4

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; en-gb; SM-T330 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/533.1

browser:    operating system: Android 4.0   primarily used on: tablet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-T530 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.117 Safari/537.36